# Magento payment method with form fields. Error: Cannot retrieve the payment method model object

Tags: magento, payment-gateway

I am creating a module for a new payment gateway (Pay On Account) that has a form field in the checkout (Only shows if user is logged in and has an account).
Mostly everything is working: The form field is captured correctly at checkout and saved in the sales_flat_order & sales_flat_quote tables.
The order code is being recorded correctly in the tables also (payonaccount)
The issue is when I try to view the order in the admin I get the following error:

```
Cannot retrieve the payment method model object.
```

Other SO answers mentioning I should correct the payment type in the DB don't work (as the payment type is correct)

Here is my code (all of it! Sorry but thanks!):

File structure:

[image]

app\code\local\Sulman\PayOnAccount\Block\Form\Payonaccount.php

```
<?php

class Sulman_PayOnAccount_Block_Form_Payonaccount extends Mage_Payment_Block_Form
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('payment/form/payonaccount.phtml');
    }
}
```

app\code\local\Sulman\PayOnAccount\Block\Info\Payonaccount.php

```
<?php

class Sulman_PayOnAccount_Block_Info_Payonaccount extends Mage_Payment_Block_Form
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('payment/info/payonaccount.phtml');
    }

    public function getMethod()
    {
        return parent::getMethod();
    }
}
```

app\code\local\Sulman\PayOnAccount\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sulman_PayOnAccount>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Sulman_PayOnAccount>
    </modules>
    <global>

        <blocks>
            <payonaccount>
                <class>Sulman_PayOnAccount_Block</class>
            </payonaccount>
        </blocks>


        <models>
            <payonaccount>
                <class>Sulman_PayOnAccount_Model</class>
            </payonaccount>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <payonaccount>
                <class>Sulman_PayOnAccount_Helper</class>
            </payonaccount>
        </helpers>
        <payment>
            <groups>
                <payonaccount>PayOnAccount</payonaccount>
            </groups>
        </payment>

        <!-- define install scripts -->
        <resources>
            <payonaccount_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Sulman_PayOnAccount</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </payonaccount_setup>
        </resources>
        <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote_payment>
                <poa_ponumber>
                    <to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment>
                </poa_ponumber>
            </sales_convert_quote_payment>
            <sales_convert_quote_payment>
                <poa_ponumber>
                    <to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment>
                </poa_ponumber>
            </sales_convert_quote_payment>

            <sales_convert_quote>
                <poa_ponumber>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </poa_ponumber>
            </sales_convert_quote>

        </fieldsets>
    </global>
    <default>
        <payment>
            <payonaccount>
                <model>payonaccount/payonaccount</model>
                <active>1</active>
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <title>Pay On Account</title>
                <payment_action>sale</payment_action>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
            </payonaccount>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

app\code\local\Sulman\PayOnAccount\Model\Payonaccount.php

```
<?php
class Sulman_PayOnAccount_Model_Payonaccount extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{
    protected $_code = 'payonaccount';
    protected $_formBlockType = 'payonaccount/form_payonaccount';
    protected $_infoBlockType = 'payonaccount/info_payonaccount';


    public function isAvailable($quote = null) {
        $isLoggedIn = Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn();
        $canPayOnAccount = false;

        if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
            $customerObj = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerData->getId());
            $hasAccount = $customerObj->getData('has_account'); // 1 = No, 2 = Yes

            if( is_null($hasAccount) OR $hasAccount == 1){
                $canPayOnAccount = false;
            } elseif($hasAccount == 2){
                $canPayOnAccount = true;
            }
        }       

        return parent::isAvailable($quote) && $canPayOnAccount;
    }

    public function assignData($data)
    {
        if (!($data instanceof Varien_Object)) {
            $data = new Varien_Object($data);
        }



        Mage::log("getPoaPonumber: ".$data->getPoaPonumber(), null, 'sulman.log');
        $this->getInfoInstance()->setPoaPonumber($data->getPoaPonumber());
        return $this;
    }
}
```

app\code\local\Sulman\PayOnAccount\sql\payonaccount_setup\mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("

ALTER TABLE `{$installer->getTable('sales/quote')}` ADD `poa_ponumber` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ;
ALTER TABLE `{$installer->getTable('sales/order')}` ADD `poa_ponumber` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ;
");
$installer->endSetup();
```

app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\payment\info\payonaccount.phtml

```
<?php
echo $this->getMethod();
?>

<p><?php //echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMethod()->getTitle()) ?></p>
```

app\design\frontend\cmtgroup\default\template\payment\form\payonaccount.phtml

```
<ul class="form-list" id="payment_form_<?php echo $this->getMethodCode() ?>" style="display:none;">
    <li>
        <label for="poa_ponumber" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Purchase Order Number') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" id="poa_ponumber" name="payment[poa_ponumber]" title="<?php echo $this->__('Purchase Order Number') ?>" class="input-text" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getInfoData('poa_ponumber')) ?>" />
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If I try and load the order elsewhere and get the poa_number like so:

```
$_order->getPoaNumber();
```

It doesn't return anything.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have solved this... I added an observer on the `sales_order_save_after` event that gets the payment info and records the poa_ponumber against the order like so:

```
public function saveBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    // get the quote of the order so we can get the quote payment type poa_ponumber
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByIdWithoutStore($order->getQuoteId());
    $poaponumber = $quote->getPayment()->getPoaPonumber();
    $order->setPoaPonumber($poaponumber);
}
```

This saves the poa_ponumber to the flat order table and can then be easily extracted the normal way: `$_order->getPoaPonumber();`

I'm sure this isn't quite the right way but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please check exist $_code in your payment method model.

You can refer :

`Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract`

Line : 343

`public function getCode()
    {
        if (empty($this->_code)) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('payment')->__('Cannot retrieve the payment method code.'));
        }
        return $this->_code;
    }`